# commandline cURL to php cURL when -d is not an array but a string

Tags: php, json, authentication, curl

Here is my commandline cURL code

```
curl -v --insecure -XPOST -H 'X-USER: nxxx' -H 'X-SIGNATURE: dxxx' -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '444' 'https://cxxx.com/api/balance'
```

it works perfect...

my problem is I am trying to convert it to php cURL and I keep getting { "error" : "AUTHENTICATION ERROR" }

Here is my latest attempt at php...

```
<?php

$json_url = "https://cxxx.com/api/balance";

// -d variable from cURL
$json_string = "444";

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-USER: nxxx';
$headers[] = 'X-SIGNATURE: dxxx';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';



$ch = curl_init($json_url);


// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string,//encoding for -d variable cURL
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
echo ($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

its because of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is set to true, you can see your curl command contains `--insecure` then this `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` must be set to false, i also wrote a code the sends the same request that the curl command you posted does, try it

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://cxxx.com/api/balance");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "444");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); //since you put --insecure
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,["X-USER: nxxx","X-SIGNATURE: dxxx","Content-type: application/json"]);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```